# URL routing - regex match with trailing slash and without

Tags: php, regex, router

I am using [Spiffy-Route](https://github.com/teresko/spiffy-route) library to route my URLs. Everything is great, able to freely route the needed urls, but I am not really able to add a wildcard, as it's not included in the api.

My route looks like this:

```
/{id:\d+}-{string}
```

Means I can route to it like this:

```
.com/5-helloworld
```

But when I route to it like this:

```
.com/5-helloworld/
```

It will not find a match, because of the slash. I have tried doing `/{id}-{string}/?` but the parameter {string} will include all the slashes after it inside it's value.

I have been going through some *Regex* questions over stackoverflow, to find out how to make the pattern support with slash and without - the common answer was `([^/]+)`, but this piece of regex doesn't really affect at all in my case.

How can I do this with Spiffy router?

If I do something like `/{id}-{string}([^/]+)/?` and route to it like this: `/5-hey/`

The output will be `5he` instead of `5hey` according to this echo:

```
echo parent::getRouteMatch()->get('id') . parent::getRouteMatch()->get('string');
```

**Will I have to modify the API to get this to work?**

Comment: Combine the ideas?  `[^/]+/?` I don't know Spiffy.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Already did, I won't get the full {string} parameter, check my edit in a sec.

Comment: Down voter, can you explain your down-vote reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[^/]` means anything but a forward slash. How about this:

```
/{id:\d+}-{string:[^/]+}\/?
```

I should note I also don't know Spiffy. Regex-wise that should work though.

If you want to allow strings after the slash, use `.*` to allow and discard, or repeat `{string:[^/]+` to capture (substitute *string* to another name in that case though)

Comment: It's including the slash inside the {string} parameter. so if your URL is `/5-hello/` your output will be `5hello/` **according to my echo code**

Comment: Hmm, ok. Just shooting blind here but try `/{id:\d+}-{string:[^/]}\/?`

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, forgot a + sign, try this: `/{id:\d+}-{string:[^/]+}\/?`

Comment: Yeah that works, just had to add .* at the end to support all after the slash `/{id:\d+}-{string:[^/]+}/?.*` Thanks